# How to write xsd schema to allow me to miss the top level tag in xsd definition?

Tags: xml, xsd, ttml

I want to create a XSD schema which is valid for both type of XML file:

```
<caption> 
    <tt>blah</tt>
</caption>
```

and

```
<tt>blah</tt>
```

And I tried `minOccurs` for caption but as it is the root it can't be `minOccurs = 0` times. So, how to achieve this?

Comment: Neither of your example instances is well-formed, so I'm not sure exactly what your question is intended to mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a tip

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
    <!-- First possible root element -->
    <xs:element name="tt" type="xs:string"/>

    <!-- Second possible root element-->
    <xs:element name="caption">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <!-- just reference to first defined element - when something change there, it won't be necessary to change it everywhere -->
                <xs:element ref="tt" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Obviously there are other ways how to reach the same effect.

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't know you can put two elemets as roots in one xsd. Will try that out and mark this accepted.

Comment: Single xsd but created two classes which I wanted to avoid. Hmm.. anyway your answer is correct for the question i asked.